# "Provide for you our service" OR "Provide our service for you"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order

"Provide for you our service" OR "Provide our service for you"?

I KNOW it's the second one, but I'm not sure why, and our copywriter wants an explanation. Can anyone explain what grammar rule dictates this?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Both phrasings are valid, though with slightly different meanings, so it's not clear what phenomenon you want a grammar rule to explain.

Comment: Well, knowing they are both correct is helpful. Thanks for being a dick about it though.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a dick, I'm asking you to clarify your question. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site works; this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site that seeks to develop a library of high-quality questions and definitive answers.

Comment: Took the tour. As someone seeking to improve their English and asking questions I have, how can I know if my question is high quality enough to be worthy of posting? I'm here because I don't know better, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't one of grammar, but rather a potential clash with the intransitive usage of *to provide*, meaning to take care of.  As an example, consider this sentence from [*Stanley 2in1 Source of My Strength and Finding Peace*](https://books.google.com/books?id=T5AzADBqHs8C&pg=PT147&dq=%22provide%20for%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRmbubtpTPAhUCHT4KHWdAC9kQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20for%20you%22&f=false) by C Stanley:

> If you doubt God's ability to **provide for you**, remind yourself of
>   the many methods He has used to provide for His people.

The appearance of a direct object after the prepositional phrase may cause a reader to readjust his expected parse.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I'll have to ponder that.